# How do you turn autosizing in a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios4

How do you turn off auto-size for subview in a UIViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
theView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
```

or you can play with the `autoresizingMask`

[autoresizesSubviews documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW10)

[autoresizingMask documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6)

Answer (score 1):

In Interface-Builder you would select the view, and switch of all red arrows in the size-tab of the Inspector panel.

In code you would write someview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;